# How to import `Chessground` with webpack 5.89.0 and `expose-loader`

Tags: javascript, webpack, expose-loader, chessground

I want to use `Chessground` (https://github.com/lichess-org/chessground) in HTML pages, plain JavaScript, no framework:

```html
<div id='board'></div>
<div id="board"></div>
<script src="assets/bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>const ground = Chessground(document.getElementById('board'), {})</script>
```

In my `webpack.config.js` I have this rule:

```js
            {
                test: require.resolve('chessground'),
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: {
                    exposes: ['Chessground'],
                },
            }
```

My webpack entry point `_assets/index.mjs` is:

```js
import { Chessground } from 'chessground';
console.log(Chessground);
```

If I run this with node 20.4.0 as `node _assets/index.mjs` it gives me `[Function: Chessground]`.

But `webpack`:

```
ERROR in ./_assets/index.mjs 2:12-23
export 'Chessground' (imported as 'Chessground') was not found in 'chessground' (module has no exports)
```

I tried to change `./_assets/index.mjs` to this:

```js
import * as Chessground from 'chessground';
console.log(Chessground);
```

Now node gives me:

```
[Module: null prototype] {
  Chessground: [Function: Chessground],
  initModule: [Function: initModule]
}
```

Now `webpack` builds the bundle without an error but it actually just contains boilerplate, no real code. Consequently in my HTML page I get this error on the console:

```
(index):44 Uncaught ReferenceError: Chessground is not defined
    at (index):44:16
(anonymous) @ (index):44
chessground-exposed.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at chessground-exposed.js:1:1
    at index.mjs:2:24
(anonymous) @ chessground-exposed.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.mjs:2
```

How can I access `Chessground` from my html pages?